# Why won't find_library find libgmp

Tags: cmake, debian

I'm trying to build a cmake project, and the repo I have been given has the lines

```
find_library(gmp gmp)
if(NOT gmp)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "gmp not found")
endif()
```

which cause CMake configuration to fail.

I have been told this CMake works on Redhat Enterprise Linux 7.3.

I have also been told this repo should build in any Linux environment with the correct libraries installed, and an Ubuntu environment has been specifically referenced.

I am building in Debian 9.4.0, I have installed gmp, `libgmp.so` is located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.2/engines/libgmp.so`
and I also have a `libgmp.so.10` at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10`.

So, to recap, I have been handed a repo I have been told builds, but it does not build, it fails at this specific step, and I can't get google to give me any relevant results on how to fix the issue/what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libgmp is installed, but the development libraries are not.

Cmake find_libraries looks for the files required for software development, and while the libgmp package is installed, the libgmp-dev package is not.

Install libgmp-dev.

Comment: Solved this problem a while ago, just noticed I hadn't chosen an answer.

Answer (score 0):

CMake **doesn't** search **"so-version"** files:

If `find_library` is called for "gmp" library name, CMake searches `libgmp.so` file, but not `libgmp.so.10` one.

Normally, the library file without so-version is just a **soft link** to the newest so-version file. If your Linux distro doesn't create such link, you may create it manually:

```
ln -s libgmp.so libgmp.so.10
```

---

If you want CMake to find `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.2/engines/libgmp.so` file, which is not under directory normally searched by CMake, you need to **hint** CMake about it. E.g. with `PATHS` option:

```
find_library(gmp gmp PATHS "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.2/engines")
```